# Ajax Post Request Returns JSON but Deferred Fails

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I have a cross-domain POST request to http://api.local/user/auth - my API endpoint. I allow Cross Domain requests in my api with CORS. Using Chrome if that makes a difference.

I get a valid server JSON response with 200 Status Code but I am using deferreds from a backbone model like so:

```
@model.save()
  .fail(-> console.log 'sync fail')
  .success ->
    console.log 'sync OK'
```

And I consistently get a 'sync fail' instead of the expected 'sync OK'

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the response content-type set to JSON? Sometimes you'll get an error response if the data type you're expecting back from the server is different from what the server sends back, even if you are getting a 200 response.

Comment: man awesome catch - thats it I think - Can I coerce the response to JSON given I don't have access to the API for a few days? Its returning as text/html right now

Comment: Use `console.log.bind(console)` instead of the function expression to log the error reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the content-type that you are expecting matches what you're receiving. If you're getting back text/html as the content type from the server, then set the `dataType` attribute to `"html"` in the request:

```
model.save({}, {dataType: "html"})....
```

(Sorry, I haven't used a lot of CoffeeScript, so I don't know the exact syntax.)

Comment: Yea tried this after reading the $.ajax documentation...even tried converting with dataType: 'html json' - didn't work. I have an ajaxPrefilter that I am using and did it through there and also your method - any other ideas?

Comment: @imrane: So you are getting JSON, but with MIME type `text/html`? Then `dataType: "json"` should work…

Comment: Yea i've tried almost all combos I can think of for dataType...including that @Bergi - this has got me stumped and I'm sure its something simple uggggh

Comment: One more thing - I'm getting parsererror - No conversion from text to http://api.local/user/auth